# How to show when click away

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I have created a mobile nav, when click on the search icon it will expand and the logo next to it will disappear by adding the class hide. But I don't know how to get the icon back when I click away. Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

**Nav bar**

[image]

**Nav bar with expanded search**

[image]

Following is the code:

```
<form class="mobile-search-container" action="https://www.tumblr.com/Search">
   <input id="search-box" type="text" class="search-box" name="q" />
   <label for="search-box"><i class="material-icons search-icon">search</i></label>
   <input type="submit" id="search-submit" />
</form>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);
</script>
<a href="#" class="header-logo d-flex flex-align-items-center" id="header-logo"></a>
<script>
    $("#search-box").click(function(){
    $("#header-logo").addClass("hide");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: When do you want to `removeClass("hide")` from the `header-logo`? What's the action that show logo?

Comment: Where is the search icon, and it seems that you want the if user clicks on search icon then the input field will appear

Comment: Use toggleClass instead of addClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `focusout` jquery event, similar to this:

```
$("#search-box").focusout(function(){
  $("#header-logo").removeClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: isn't it called .blur ?

Comment: f.ocusout is more appropriate. As in the jquery docs (https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) 

This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the icon wherever clicked other than search-box, so you can do it when body clicked:

```
$('body').click(function(){
    $("#header-logo").removeClass("hide");
});
```

however clicking on search-box will also fire the body.click so you should prevent body from being clicked when search-box is clicked by adding `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$("#search-box").click(function(e){
    $("#header-logo").addClass("hide");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I tried that and it didnt work, turns out it's focus and blur =] but thank you!